# Compare input value with li content in pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have to do some kind of ToDo list, where I have input and button to Add item to ul list. And now I done everything except compare every li item with input value. My question is how to compare every li content with value input to prevent duplicate items. Here is the code https://jsfiddle.net/qoLtxfaw/1/

```js
// Variables
var ul = document.getElementById("taskList");
var task = document.getElementById("task");
var btn = document.querySelector('button');
var listItem = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");

// Append close btn to each list item
for (var i = 0; i < listItem.length; i++) {
  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "js-close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  listItem[i].appendChild(span);
}

// Click on a close button to hide the current list item
var close = document.getElementsByClassName("js-close");
for (var i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
  close[i].onclick = function() {
    var div = this.parentElement;
    div.className = 'js-hide';
  }
}

// proveravati ima li ul odnosno liste, ukoliko ne proverimo a nema ceo kod ce prestati da se izvrsava
if (ul) {
  ul.onmouseover = function(event) {
    var target = event.target;
    target.style.background = '#efebeb';
  };

  ul.onmouseout = function(event) {
    var target = event.target;
    target.style.background = '';
  };
}

// Add item to list on btn
btn.addEventListener('click', addItem);

// Add item to list on enter
task.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    addItem();
  }
};

// // Add item to list
function addItem() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var inputValue = document.getElementById('task').value;
  li.setAttribute('id', task.value);
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(task.value));
  // ul.appendChild(li);

  // compare every li item with inputValue
  if (inputValue) { //if input value is true and has some value
    //go trough all li items
    for (var i = 0; i < listItem.length; i++) {
      // compare every li item with inputValue

    }

    // Duplicate values don't allow in list
    if (!inputValue) {
      alert("No empty values are allowed!");
      li.className = 'js-btn-disable';
    } else {
      ul.appendChild(li);
    }
    document.getElementById("task").value = "";


    var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
    var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
    span.className = "js-close";
    span.appendChild(txt);
    li.appendChild(span);

    for (var i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
      close[i].onclick = function() {
        var div = this.parentElement;
        div.className = 'js-hide';
      }
    }
  }

}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #00bcd4;
  border: 1px solid #f1f0f0;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

#wrapper #task {
  background: transparent;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 80%;
  height: 35px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
  outline: none;
  margin: 15px 0 5px 0;
}

#wrapper #task ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: #ffffff;
}

#wrapper #task ::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: #ffffff;
}

#wrapper #task :-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* IE 10+ */
  color: #ffffff;
}

#wrapper #task :-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 18- */
  color: #ffffff;
}

#wrapper button {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  background: transparent;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#wrapper ul#taskList {
  padding: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

#wrapper ul#taskList li {
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Style the close button */

.js-close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.js-close:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.js-hide {
  display: none;
}

.js-background {
  background: #efebeb;
}

.js-btn-disable {
  opacity: 0.65;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}


/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <input type="text" id="task" />
  <button>Add</button>

  <ul id="taskList"></ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Where is your code? :)

Comment: Please show us your attempt first.

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt keep calm and take it easy ;)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. If you want someone to actually answer your question, It is suggested that you provide some code so people know that you actually tried to solve it yourself first. We don't do other people's homework

Comment: @MuhammadSalman Thanks, I'm new with this so I didn't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this. I use firstChild and I moved the validation to the top of the function.

I use the inputValue after validating it but task everywhere else.

DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself

```js
// Variables
var ul = document.getElementById("taskList");
var task = document.getElementById("task");
var btn = document.querySelector('button');
var listItem = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
task.focus();

// Append close btn to each list item
for (var i = 0; i < listItem.length; i++) {
  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "js-close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  listItem[i].appendChild(span);
}

// Click on a close button to hide the current list item
var close = document.getElementsByClassName("js-close");
for (var i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
  close[i].onclick = function() {
    var div = this.parentElement;
    div.className = 'js-hide';
  }
}

// proveravati ima li ul odnosno liste, ukoliko ne proverimo a nema ceo kod ce prestati da se izvrsava
if (ul) {
  ul.onmouseover = function(event) {
    var target = event.target;
    target.style.background = '#efebeb';
  };

  ul.onmouseout = function(event) {
    var target = event.target;
    target.style.background = '';
  };
}

// Add item to list on btn
btn.addEventListener('click', addItem);

// Add item to list on enter
task.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    addItem();
  }
};

// // Add item to list
function addItem() {
  var inputValue = task.value.trim();
  task.value = "";
  task.focus();
  
  // Empty or  Duplicate values don't allow in list
  if (!inputValue) {
    alert("No empty values are allowed!");
    return
  }

  var listItem = document.querySelectorAll("#taskList li");
  for (var i = 0; i < listItem.length; i++) {
    if (inputValue == listItem[i].firstChild.textContent) {
      alert("No duplicate values are allowed!");
      return
    }
  }


  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.setAttribute('id', inputValue);
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(inputValue));
  ul.appendChild(li);


  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "js-close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  li.appendChild(span);

  for (var i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
    close[i].onclick = function() {
      var div = this.parentElement;
      div.className = 'js-hide';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #00bcd4;
  border: 1px solid #f1f0f0;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

#wrapper #task {
  background: transparent;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 80%;
  height: 35px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
  outline: none;
  margin: 15px 0 5px 0;
}

#wrapper #task ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: #ffffff;
}

#wrapper #task ::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: #ffffff;
}

#wrapper #task :-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* IE 10+ */
  color: #ffffff;
}

#wrapper #task :-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 18- */
  color: #ffffff;
}

#wrapper button {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  background: transparent;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#wrapper ul#taskList {
  padding: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

#wrapper ul#taskList li {
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Style the close button */

.js-close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.js-close:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.js-hide {
  display: none;
}

.js-background {
  background: #efebeb;
}

.js-btn-disable {
  opacity: 0.65;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}


/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <input type="text" id="task" />
  <button>Add</button>

  <ul id="taskList"></ul>

</div>
```